# handling repeated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

re: **repeated questions**

I think repeated questions may be handled in a slightly better way.  Currently usually what happens is a link is posted to the duplicate question, and the new question is closed down.

It'd be better if there were some way to *merge* duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to merge duplicates. Moderators can do it. Flag for moderator attention citing the duplicate.